# Fixed element not being centered by jquery on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I have 3 elements that are supposed to be centered by jQuery upon page load. Currently, only 2 of the elements are centered correctly by **Safari** on desktop and mobile. `#pulse_ball` is the element that is not being positioned correctly; it gets a `left` style of `-0.5px` for some reason. After resize, however, all 3 elements are centered correctly. Also (on iPhone) in portrait mode the elements get centered correctly after a scroll, but not in landscape mode.

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sd7z6jvd/)

**CSS for #pulse_ball:**

```
#pulse_ball {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: calc(50% - 27px);
    z-index: 25;
    top: 48%;
}
```

**CSS for #center_line:**

```
#center_line {
    width: 3px;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

**CSS for #arrow_down:**

```
#arrow_down {
    display: block;
    width: 64px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: calc(50% - 32px);
}
```

**JS code:**

```
centerItems();

$(window).resize(function() {
    centerItems();
});

function centerItems() {
    $("#center_line").height($("body").height());
    $("#center_line").offset({left: ($("body").width() / 2) - 1});
    $("#pulse_ball").offset({left: ($("body").width() / 2) - ($("#pulse_ball").width() / 2)});
    $("#arrow_down").offset({left: ($("body").width() / 2) - ($("#arrow_down").width() / 2)});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a css `calc()` problem, try setting only `left: 50%` for the `#pulse_ball` elememnt. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/elrumordelaluz/jo97ksn0/2/) is the fork working.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Seems strange that #arrow_down was being centered correctly since it used calc() as well.

Comment: yes, it is weird, try also changing `left: calc(50% - 27px);` into `right: calc(50% - 27px);` or `top: 48%;` into `bottom: xx%`. There is some issue in Safari calculations anyway.